# Keywords lookup in Spark Scala based on position

Tags: scala, apache-spark, lookup

I've 2 files as shown below.

Keyword file

```
spark
scala
hive
```

Content file

```
this is spark.
this can be scala and spark.
this is hive.
```

My aim is to lookup the keywords in each line of the content file. While searching, I should be able to get only the last occurance of the key word ( i.e. even though if the content contains 2 keyword, I should take only the last occurance) and create a csv file to load the data into hive table.

Expected output

```
"this is spark.","spark"
"this can be scala and spark.","spark"
"this is hive.","hive"
```

My content file has millions of rows. what is the best & optimized way to get the output

Comment: Can you show how you are currently trying to approach the problem and how you think it is not "optimized"?

Answer (score 1):

Question is very abstract, assuming that contents are loaded into RDD, and keywords are loaded into a list, below code works.

```
scala> val contents = sc.parallelize(Seq("this is spark.","this can be scala and spark.","this is hive."))
contents: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[137] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> val keywordsRdd = sc.parallelize(Seq("spark", "scala", "hive"))
keywordsRdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[138] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> val keywords:List[String] = keywordsRdd.collect.toList
keywords: List[String] = List(spark, scala, hive)

scala> val mappedData = contents.flatMap(x=>x.split(",")).map(x => (x,x.split("\\s+").last.replaceAll("[.]",""))).filter(x=> keywords.contains(x._2)).collect.foreach(println)
(this is spark.,spark)
(this can be scala and spark.,spark)
(this is hive.,hive)
```